# ServiceStack 4: not able to add Expires Header for static content

Tags: caching, servicestack, static-content, expires-header, servicestack-razor

In my web.config, I am trying to add caching for static content:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Sun, 1 Jan 2020 00:00:00 UTC" />
    </staticContent>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

However, when I run YSlow! I still get a grade F for "Add Expires Header"; so, it seems like static content like images, CSS and Javascript files are not getting cached.

How can I accomplish this in ServiceStack since the web.config changes I made don't get picked up by ServiceStack; this does work in ASP.NET MVC, but how do I server static content with expires headers?

I also tried this, but my static files are still not getting cached.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: the `<staticContent>` xml config has no effect on Web Frameworks that provide their own static file handling functionality like ServiceStack.

Static Files in ServiceStack are handled by [StaticFileHandler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/Handlers/StaticFileHandler.cs) which automatically appends HTTP Headers useful for caching Static files like the `Last-Modified` header which is used to send an empty `304 Not Modified` Response when requests are made to static files that haven't changed since they were last requested.

#### Adding Max-Age to Static Files

In addition, there's an option for specifying `Cache-Control: max-age={Seconds}` for specific file types, which by default includes max ages for Image Content-Types e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    AddMaxAgeForStaticMimeTypes = {
        { "image/gif", TimeSpan.FromHours(1) },
        { "image/png", TimeSpan.FromHours(1) },
        { "image/jpeg", TimeSpan.FromHours(1) },
    }
});
```

You can also modify and extend the above defaults with additional Content Types.

#### Adding Custom Static File Headers

New in **v4.0.33+** is the `StaticFileHandler.ResponseFilter` which you can use to append your own custom headers on static files, e.g this adds a custom HTTP `Expires` header for `.txt` files that expires in 1 hour:

```
StaticFileHandler.ResponseFilter = (req, res, file) => {
    if (file.Extension == "txt")
        res.AddHeader("Expires", DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToString("r"));
};
```

This change is now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).